# How to fix broken tzdata2020c timezone database for alpine?

Tags: go, alpine-linux, tzdata

I just stumbled upon a bug with the tzdata2020c package for alpine. It does not calculate the correct time for Europe/Berlin after the scheduled change of daylight savings time next Sunday October 25th, 2020. Version tzdata2020c uses CEST for e.g. the 31st of October 2020 and Europe/Berlin timezone whereas CET would be correct.

Does anybody know how to manually add a new version of the tzdata2020d database which is available [here](https://www.iana.org/time-zones).

My application, written in Go, incorrectly uses CEST for Europe/Berlin at 31st October 2020 using tzdata2020c:
[image: tzdata2020c]

The same application correctly uses CET for Europe/Berlin at 31st October 2020 using tzdata2020a:
[image: tzdata2020a]

Comment: I have duplicated this issue; [the playground](https://play.golang.org/p/UKbk7o5TF7H) performs as expected as do the docker images `golang:latest` and `golang:alpine`. However if I install the timezone data in the alpine image (`apk add tzdata`) the results are incorrect (all times in `CEST`). Running `export ZONEINFO=/usr/local/go/lib/time/zoneinfo.zip` fixes this (so quick fix would be to take that approach).

Answer (score 3):

Manually installing the `tzdata2020d` files will not, in itself, fix this. However the following should (successfully tested with the `golang:alpine` docker image):

```
mkdir tz
cd tz
wget https://www.iana.org/time-zones/repository/releases/tzdata2020d.tar.gz
tar -xvf tzdata2020d.tar.gz
zic -b fat -d zoneinfo/ europe
cp zoneinfo/Europe/Berlin /usr/share/zoneinfo/Europe/Berlin
```

Other workarounds include:

- Upgrade to Go [1.15.4](https://github.com/golang/go/issues?q=milestone%3AGo1.15.4+label%3ACherryPickApproved) or [1.14.11](https://github.com/golang/go/issues?q=milestone%3AGo1.14.11+label%3ACherryPickApproved).
- Use the `ZONEINFO` [environmental variable](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#LoadLocation) to select a different zone file (e.g. `export ZONEINFO=/usr/local/go/lib/time/zoneinfo.zip`; `zoneinfo.zip` is in the [go installation](https://github.com/golang/go/tree/dev.boringcrypto.go1.15/lib/time)).
- Include the [tzdata](https://golang.org/pkg/time/tzdata/) package in your app (and do not install tzdata in the container - the package is only used if the time package cannot find tzdata files on the system).
- Use a container built from [scratch](https://hub.docker.com/_/scratch) (in combination with one of the above options)
- Pin an earlier alpine version (i.e. alpine:3.8) that [uses 2020a](https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/packages?name=tzdata&branch=v3.8) or earlier (note that version 3.8 is past its [End of Support](https://wiki.alpinelinux.org/wiki/Alpine_Linux:Releases) date).

### Cause

This problem was caused by a change in the `zic` application; prior to the version included with [2020b](https://data.iana.org/time-zones/releases/tzcode2020b.tar.gz) release this defaulted to `fat` mode which go applications correctly processed. The default is now `thin` and go does not support that format (without this [patch](https://github.com/golang/go/commit/d83168eb385f7ae38710028fff5c84252267adbc)). Unfortunately the `LoadLocation` function fails silently (returning incorrect zone information).

The issue is likely to occur wherever 2020b or later timezone files are used (unless the package maintainer overrides the defaults when running `zic`).

### `zic` details

[iana](https://www.iana.org/) distributes the timezone information as a series of [text files](https://data.iana.org/time-zones/releases/tzdata2020d.tar.gz) along with a number of [applications](https://data.iana.org/time-zones/releases/tzcode2020d.tar.gz). One of these applications is `zic` which processes the text files into the binary files ([RFC 8536](https://tools.ietf.org/html/8536)) which are deployed to `/usr/share/zoneinfo`.

[This commit](https://github.com/eggert/tz/commit/6ba6f2117b95eab345a7ed9159cef939e30c4cd3#diff-2a9ebfd8ed1e3a34e3d9596f4034630491b01711efcf3e10cbd5967caf431eff) changed the default output format from `fat` to `slim`. The upshot of this is that timezone files produced using the 2020b, or later, files will not be read correctly by Go (unless they are created using the `-b fat` argument).

### Go Fix

*This is fixed in Go [1.15.4](https://github.com/golang/go/issues?q=milestone%3AGo1.15.4+label%3ACherryPickApproved) and [1.14.11](https://github.com/golang/go/issues?q=milestone%3AGo1.14.11+label%3ACherryPickApproved).*

An [issue](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/42138) has been raised and the issue is partly fixed by a recent [commit](https://github.com/golang/go/commit/d83168eb385f7ae38710028fff5c84252267adbc) (the main aim of that commit was to reduce the size of the `time/tzdata` package but should also fix this). See [this issue](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/42216) re the other part of the fix.

### Testing

The following application demonstrates the issue:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    b, err := time.LoadLocation("Europe/Berlin")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    t := time.Date(2020, 10, 23, 11, 00, 00, 00, time.UTC)
    fmt.Printf("1: %s %s\n", t, t.In(b))
    t = time.Date(2020, 10, 31, 11, 00, 00, 00, time.UTC)
    fmt.Printf("2: %s %s\n", t, t.In(b))
}
```

The output (Alpine 3.12 under Docker), as at 19th October, is:

```
1: 2020-10-23 11:00:00 +0000 UTC 2020-10-23 13:00:00 +0200 CEST
2: 2020-10-31 11:00:00 +0000 UTC 2020-10-31 13:00:00 +0200 CEST
```

This is incorrect because the 31st should be `CET` (Alpine 3.8 generates the correct result).

Comment: Fixed since Go 1.15.4: [issue #42138](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/42138#issuecomment-719062698) is on [milestone 1.15.4](https://github.com/golang/go/milestone/177?closed=1) or see [release-notes](https://golang.org/doc/devel/release.html#go1.15.minor).